# What is the difference in between those pieces of code?

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout, setinterval

What is the difference in between:

```
k = setInterval(function(){loop();},100);
```

and

```
k = setInterval(loop(),100);
```

Why does the second one run once, like the setTimeout() function and the first one every 1/10 of a second?

Comment: Seems like `setInterval(loop,100);` would be the right way to write that

Comment: When you have `foo(bar())`, then `bar` is executed first and its return value is passed to `foo`. Arguments are **always** evaluated first. Don't let yourself get confused by the fact that `setTimeout` accepts a function. That has nothing to do with how arguments evaluated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In second one you are actually executing `loop` before `setInterval` is called, so you are passing result of the `loop` to the `setInterval`

More similar would be

```
k = setInterval(function(){loop();},100);

k = setInterval(loop,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

first example allows you to do some work before calling loop and to pass some arguments if necessary

second one requires a function object as a 1st parameter and you cannot pass anything inside the brackets.

1st one is more widely spread pattern than 2nd (which is a little bit obsolete)

Comment: What do you mean by obsolete? The 2nd one is not correct. I think you're confusing it with `setInterval('loop()',100)` which is correct but unnecessary. This answer is misleading.

Comment: please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval - Syntax section. 1st parameter must be a function object or code than might be evaluated as a function. So 'loop()' is equal to eval('loop()') which will result as an anonymous function that will call loop function or will throw an error if it does not exists.

Comment: So you are confirming what @elclanrs just said. You are confusing `setInterval(loop(),100)` (no quotes) with `setInterval('loop()',100)` (with quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Lets checkout how doest JS run this code:

Fist way -

JS see setInterval - it should have 2 arguments and timer - in first variant everythink is trivial - you **passed** a function to be called on each interval and timer.

Lets check second variant - again setInterval, 2 params . But this time you dont pass link to function but **called** function and the result of this function will be passed to the setInterval. As you called function - it runs once, as it doesent return function setInterval cant run anything.